# SSIS refuse to run some packages

Tags: ssis

I have an SSIS project that has 5 packages in it.

```
+MyAwesomeProject
 -Package
 -CoolPackage
 -AwesomePackage
 -HyperPackage
 -FinalPackage
```

The startup package is "Package" and that one is only a holder that will call the packages in order, first Cool, then Awesome and so on.

If I run the project from Visual Studio it works perfectly and does everything I want... perfectly. No errors, no questions, everything just works.

When I deploy the script, set up an SQL job with a correct user running the job and with exactly the same parameters as the Visual Studio job it will run without errors, but skip doing the packages CoolPackage, AwesomePackage and HyperPackage. It will execute the code in Package and then, instead of doing all four packages in order as is defined in Package it will skip to FinalPackage.

Since everything works perfectly in Visual Studio, I don't even know where to begin looking.

Comment: Start with the SSIS error logs.   The most likely cause is the permissions of the SQL Agent.

Comment: I found out why, but it spawns another question. It DID run all packages, but the first thing that happens in Cool, Awesome and Hyper package is that it connects to an FTP server, downloads files and then iterates over those files. I don't connect to the place where the files are stored but only use \\server\folder\subfolder to point where to store the ftp files and to iterate over. The SQL job didn't have permission to read from there and thus it failed, but it spawned NO error. It just said "transfered all files from ftp to local disk" (i.e. the \\server e.tc disk) and then "iteration empty"

Comment: Did the job have permission to connect, but not to see those files?  If so, then I don't think that would be an error.  You'll probably have to write some custom code to have it raise an error if it can't find the expected files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was actually not a case of the packages not running, it was a case of the package not executing their content perfectly.

To check if a package have run properly you need to navigate to the package in the MSSMS (SQL Studio) in the left "Object Explorer". When you have located your package (under "Integration Service Catalogs" -> "SSISDB" -> "[Package Folder]" -> "Projects" -> "[Package Name]") you right click it and choose "Reports" -> "Standard Reports" -> "All Executions". This will bring up a report you can drill down into and see exactly what has run and what has not run.

This solved my problem for me.